# pattern recognition and string matching

Tags: c++, perl

I have two files taken from two different server. In these two files are presents the matches of some football teams. As you know football teams can be called with differents names.
I would like  implement a code that can recognise the same football match in the two files in order to take same variables from a file and some other from the other file.
for example in one file i  have a match called

```
Derry City - Bray Wanderers
```

and in the other file i have the same match that is called

```
Derry City - Bray
```

how can i do this?
i have no ideas.

Comment: Seriously, **no** ideas at all? Not even incomplete, or wrong, or naïve ones?

Comment: The only naive idea is to parse one file with search and replace subroutine with sed or perl. But for every new teams i have to fix the file manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple script to replace aliases for teams. You'll need to fill it with aliases yourself, I made some up. If you have multiple games, the hash will overwrite the existing ones, as long as all the aliases are exchanged for full names.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %games;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($home, $guest) = split /\s*-\s*/, $_, 2;
    $home  = get_name($home);
    $guest = get_name($guest);
    $games{"$home - $guest"} = 1;
}

sub get_name {
# Return the full name for the team, if it exists, otherwise return the original
    my %alias = (
        'Derry'     => 'Derry City',
        'Brawlers'  => 'Beijing',
        'Dolphins'  => 'Miami',
        'Bray'      => 'Bray Wanderers',
    );
    return $alias{$_[0]} // $_[0];
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%games;

__DATA__
Derry City - Bray Wanderers
Derry City - Bray
Brawlers - Dolphins
Beijing - Miami
Miami - Beijing
```

Answer (score 1):

In c++: Have a look at [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/libs/regex/) and [Boost.Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/libs/tokenizer/) as they will do what you need.  All you need is a pattern to match.

```
boost::regex("Bray[\s]*(Wanderers)?", boost::regex::icase);
```

Or something like that -- easy to set up as a set of unit tests.